# Find the bounds as tight as possible?

Tags: big-o, asymptotic-complexity, upperbound

```
2^n −8 = O(2^n)
It says there are some positive constants c and n0 for which
0 <= f(n) <= cg(n) for all n >= n0
```

I solved it as:

```
2^n −8 <= c2^n
If c = 1, and n0 = 1
1-8 <= 1*1
-7<= 1
then for all n >= n0 it remains true.
```

which is true but I don't understand what is the meaning of  Find the bounds as tight as possible ? 
Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As tight as possible* means finding a function `g(n)` with *smallest* order of growth such that it still satisfies `f(n) = O(g(n))`. In your example it is relatively straightforward (hence your confusion, I believe) - just remove everything but the fastest growing term (`2^n`).

However let's consider an example where the tightest bound might not be immediately obvious - the Fibonacci sequence generator: `f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2)`. A simple way to find an upper bound would be to make an approximation, by replacing `n - 2` with `n - 1` to give `f(n) ≈ 2 * f(n - 1)`, which is `O(2^n)`. This is not the *tightest* bound though - by solving a quadratic equation you will find that the tightest bound is in fact `Ө(1.61...^n)` - see [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65011/prove-this-formula-for-the-fibonacci-sequence) for more details.

Comment: Is my solution is okay, as considered to the upper tightest.

Comment: @MuhammadHamza yes your solution is correct; as I said, the reason for your question may be because the answer in this case was deceptively simple, making you confused about the *point* of the question